# convergence in distribution for Poisson

Tags: measure-theory

$\newcommand{\Poi}{\operatorname{Poi}}$I try to show that if $X_n$ converges to $Z$ in distribution, that

$\Poi(X_n)$ converges in distribution to $\Poi(Z)$,

with Poi, i mean a Poisson distribution.

So I need to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} E[f(\Poi(X_n))]=E[f(\Poi(Z))]$.
I thought about using tower property but I am not sure if
$E[E[f(\Poi(X_n))\mid X_n]]=E[f(X_n)]$ holds. How can I show that?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline/Sketch:**

My first instinct would be to use [characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)): you want to show, that, for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $$\mathbb{E}[e^{it Y_n}] \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \mathbb{E}[e^{it Y}]$$ where $Y_n\sim\operatorname{Poi}(X_n)$ and  $Y\sim\operatorname{Poi}(Z)$ (this is because of [Lévy's convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem)). You can use conditioning to get $$\mathbb{E}[e^{it Y_n}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{it Y_n}\mid X_n]] = \mathbb{E}[ e^{X_n(e^{it}-1)} ]$$ using the [expression the characteristic function of a Poisson r.v.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Examples); and similarly $$\mathbb{E}[e^{it Y}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{it Y}\mid Z]] = \mathbb{E}[ e^{Z(e^{it}-1)} ]$$so it only remains to use the convergence assumption on $(X_n)_n$ to show that $$\mathbb{E}[ e^{X_n(e^{it}-1)} ] \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \mathbb{E}[ e^{Z(e^{it}-1)} ]$$ for every fixed $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

*(This last part would be trivial if $i(e^{it}-1)$ were a real number, as it would then be a direct consequence of $X_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{\mathcal{D}} Z$ by Lévy's theorem; but even without this, it should not be too much of a problem.)*

Comment: Is it right than I can use the momentgenerating function instead of the characteristic funktion because of the link below and therefore I do not have complex numbers anymore so it follows directly? Thanks for your help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25474/moment-generating-function

Comment: @Mathfreak Yes, if you use the MGF (which exists and is well-defined here) instead of the characteristic function, these considerations should disappear and things should go through -- since then you only have real values everywhere.